# asp.net dropdown displaying incorrectly in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, webforms, html-select

I have asp.net web forms page that has a asp.net dropdownlist control on it with an autopostback.  When a user makes a selection in the drop down a get request is made to the same page with a query string parameter.

On postback I read the query string parameter and load / populate additional controls.

When a user presses the browsers back button the previous request is submitted (along with its query string).  In the code behind I read the query string and load / populate additional controls, which works fine.  I also try to select the appropriate item in the drop down (by value).

The issue I am seeing in the browser is that appropriate option **text** is not shown in the select.  By inspecting the source I can see the the correct option has the selected="selected" attribute, so setting the selected item in the code behind was successful.  But the text is incorrectly still the same as before the back button was pressed.

Curiously this only happens in chrome. ie and firefox both behave as expected.

Has anyone had any issues with asp.net drop down lists and chrome?

I'm stumped here.

I have created a simple example that demonstates this problem.  src can be found at https://github.com/beembow/AspDotNetDropDownInChrome.git

Reproduce the error by selecting some values in drop down then pressing back button.

Comment: Please show some of your code e.g. bind data part, page_load, aspx markup page etc, also, you mean displaying incorrectly in chrome, what about in IE, firefox? did they work properly, if so, are there any errors shown in the developer tools?

Comment: Will try and add some code this morning ... but I believe my companies policies will prevent me from doing so ... maybe I see if I can create an equivalent example.  This problem is not present in firefox and ie, they display the correct text in the drop down.

Comment: I should clarify, that the dropdown selection changed fires a postback and the handler for this event does a Response.Redirect to the same page with a query string (a GET).  The Page_Load event then reads the query string and loads additional fields and sets the appropriate value in the drop down.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885338/asp-net-google-chrome-caching-dropdownlist-selections which I believe is the same problem I am having, but perhaps explained better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They only fix I have found is similar to the one suggested [ASP.NET - Google Chrome caching DropDownList selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885338/asp-net-google-chrome-caching-dropdownlist-selections).

I essentially add a global variable that holds the value of the option to select in the drop down.  I do this via Page.RegisterStartupScript in the code behind.

I then have some js that looks for this global value, and if it finds it selects the appropriate option in the select via jquery.

This makes me think that the issue is something to do with how chrome treats some asp.net generated javascript / viewstate.  It may also be something to do with chrome caching policies.  curious that it works in both firefox and ie.

Either way, the solution described above is definitely an ugly hack.  Would be interested in any solutions other people find.

Answer (score 0):

In which Page Event are you setting the selected value of the drop-down? It could be that you are setting it once the page is loaded, and that is why you don't see the dropdown set with the selected value.

Comment: It is set in a private method which is called from the Page_Load event handler

Comment: Is the dropdown being populated in code behind? When are you binding the dropdown? Is the EnableViewState property enabled? Definitely need your code to debug this issue.